# Wicket 1.5 and obtaining a URL to page instance

Tags: url, wicket, wicket-1.5

What is to correct way in Wicket 1.5 to obtain URL to a page instance?

In Wicket 1.4.x this worked:

```java
MyPage page = new MyPage(some, parameters);
getRequestCycle().urlFor(page).toString()
```

A bunch of different versions of `urlFor()` were removed from [RequestCycle in Wicket 1.5](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/request/cycle/RequestCycle.html), among these were [urlFor(Page page)](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/RequestCycle.html#urlFor%28org.apache.wicket.Page%29) that I was using in Wicket 1.4.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need: org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle#urlFor(IRequestHandler).

```
cycle.urlFor(new RenderPageRequestHandler(new PageProvider(page)))
```

I'm not sure why this wasn't migrated. I guess because it is not used widely...

Comment: Actually doing this also works and it's shorter: `getRequestCycle().urlFor(YourPage.class, null)`

Comment: @Glide: No. This is not the same. The OP asks for page *instance*.

Comment: Yup, disregard my comment.

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.urlFor was renamed to org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.urlFor (See [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/migration-to-wicket-15.html#MigrationtoWicket1.5-Listofrenamedclassesandmethods))

[edit]
My bad. Try

```
RequestCycle.get().getUrlRenderer().renderFullUrl(Url.parse(urlFor(MyPage.class,null).toString()));
```

(taken from [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/getting-a-url-for-display.html))

Comment: That is not the problem. The problem is that interface for urlFor() method changed in 1.4->1.5 upgrade.

Comment: that generates a static link to MyPage where new MyPage instance is created with no-args or PageParameters constructor. I need a version that creates an URL for existing page instance (new MyPage("somevalue", "someothervalue", etc) )

Comment: Downvoted because the question was explicitly about a page instance (not a page type).

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
RequestUtils.toAbsolutePath(urlFor(MyPage.class, params).toString(), "/");
```

See [JavaDoc of RequestUtils](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/protocol/http/RequestUtils.html#toAbsolutePath%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [Component as suplier for urlFor](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#urlFor%28java.lang.Class,%20org.apache.wicket.PageParameters%29) for the (scarce) details... But the interface should be pretty selfexplaining. Just supply the target class and the PageParams-Object and be (mostly) done

Comment: This only works with page instances that have no-args constructor or ones that take PageParameters as parameter. MyPage is neither.

Comment: Downvoted because the question was explicitly about a page instance (not a page type).